# How to show add-in icon in the menu bar of Outlook for Web?

Tags: outlook-addin, manifest, outlook-web-addins

I would like to show my add-in icon in the menu bar ,like the following the red circle,  in the Outlook for Web.

[image]

How can I write manifest file to show my icon like that?

I found Script Lab, which is the add-in  produced by Microsoft, achieved that.

Comment: If its for Message surface then please go to Settings > Mail > Customise Actions > And then in the Message Surface option please select the required addin.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
When I installed Script-Lab, I could  show the icon like that without any setting.
Can I show the icon without any setting by user if I rewrite manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, today we only allow the add-in to be shown on the email surface at the time of install through the App Store inside of Outlook Web, or using the Customise Actions pane in Outlook. This cannot be declared inside of an Add-in manifest. If you want to raise a request for the feature you can do so on our
[uservoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=131778). We go through the requests on our uservoice page when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will raise a request. Thank you!